# Why does this conditional statement not work?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this function in PHP to check if a number is 1 or 0, and if it isn't to die no access. This is for a lightweight security system implemented in one of my games to help prevent most cheating.

```
$number = 1;
if ($number<>0 || $number<>1){
    die("nope");
}
```

However, when I run this code above, nope is echoed. Why?

Comment: your first condition is true so it is always inside if

Comment: Because 1 is not equal to 0 so it's true.  You want `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <> comparison operator is the same as != (not equal). The || is an OR comparison operator. In the conditional statement above if either expression is not true, the code block will execute. since 1 != 0, the code block will execute.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if `$number` is greater/less than 0 OR greater/less than 1.  Since 1 is greater than 0 the first  condition is true and the statement is true.  So you get the message 'nope'.

Change it to this:

```
if ($number <> 0 && $number <> 1){
```

Comment: `<>` means "not equal to", it's the same as `!=`.

Comment: Being "not equal" would mean that it is either greater or less than.

Comment: I guess.  I've never heard it explained that way :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your code always pass, it checks if $number is NOT one or is NOT zero - try proper solution:

```
$number=1;
if (!($number==0 || $number==1)){
  die("nope");
}
```

Comment: @RocketHazmat why not?

Comment: is not before condition

Answer (score 2):

your first condition `$number<>0` is true. `<>` means not equal to(`!=`). `1 != 0`  is true.

so it is always inside if condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition `$number<>0 || $number<>1` will be true when `$number` is 1 because 1 is not equal to 0.  Since you are using `||`, it will short-circuit since `true || <anything>` is true.

You want to use `&&` here instead.  To check whether `$number` is not equal to either 0 or 1.

```
$number=1;
if ($number<>0 && $number<>1){
  die("nope");
}
```

Following [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you can also do:

```
$number=1;
if (!($number==0 || $number==1)){
  die("nope");
}
```